# Push events to icloud calendar from my Web Application

Tags: c#, .net, angular

One of the options I have come across is to build a CalDav client. But from what I understand it will require user to share their credentials(login/password). This is not feasible.

Another option was to use DDay.iCal (https://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/). But the support for this is long past and their are a lot of issues reported.

The Use case is to allow the user to view events created in the web application on their iPhone calendar. Allow users to follow a calendar.

Are their API's or libraries that could help in achieving the functionality?

The nearest solution is https://www.calendarx.com/. How are they integrating the events to iCloud?

Comment: Sharing credential can use a User Group where each user has their own login and password.  You probably have group accounts already if you have a corporate network using Group Policy.  The SQL Server has options to use Windows Credentials for a database.  The Group would be a window user group which you are already using if you a accessing files from network drives.

Comment: We do not have a "corporate network using Group Policy". I am talking about remote users being able to follow events on our web app. By seeing the events on their personal calendars.

Comment: Remote users do not have credentials to directly access database.  It would have to be done through scripts on the webpage.  See : https://cloud.google.com/dotnet/docs/getting-started/using-sql-server

Comment: This does not lead to creating iCalender events and syncing them with the users iCloud Calendar. 
__
PS: Removed the Sql tag as it is apparently misleading

Comment: An ICalendar Event is just a click event on a calendar cell.  So your html for each cell would call a method with a date.  Then the method would save the data to the database.  Have you checked codeproject for similar web calendar?

Comment: Web calendars exist, far and wide. My query is regarding allowing viewers to follow a calendars events. Pushing events to their personal calendar accounts (most importantly iCloud calendar).

Comment: See Microsoft API : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations

Comment: Does something of this sort exist that also syncs with (supports) icloud.com/calendar. This is lead is helpful, closer to what I am looking into.

Comment: See http://www.akruto.com/how-to-sync-icloud-calendar-to-outlook/  Also see : https://www.quora.com/Will-Apple-iCloud-also-publish-an-API-to-read-write-the-calendar-data